# According to JsonAPI specs, why disallow bulk updates?

Tags: api, json-api

I quoted the notice in the ebook about Json API design. They said that

[image]

I need a detail example and an explaination of the reason why bulk updates must be forbidden.

Comment: in your quoted text is word: **may** not *must*

Answer (score 0):

The text you have quoted is misleading. The specification requires a `PATCH` request to either *"either completely replace every member of the relationship, return an appropriate error response if some resources can not be found or accessed, or return a 403 Forbidden response if complete replacement is not allowed by the server."* ([Source](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-to-many-relationships)) But this is not the reason you should consider disallowing replacement of to-many relationships.

The specification lists one of the reasons you may consider to disallow it as a note:

> Since full replacement (of to-many relationships) may be a very dangerous operation, a server may choose to disallow it. For example, a server may reject full replacement if it has not provided the client with the full list of associated objects, and does not want to allow deletion of records the client has not seen. ([Source](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-resource-relationships))

Another common issue are collisions. Lets assume clients A and B requests a resource including the full list of associated objects. If both are associating another objects and using full replacement via PATCH therefore, the second request will override the first one and therefore *delete* the relationship created by the first request without even knowing about it.

Updating relationship via `POST` and `DELETE` using [relationship links](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-relationships) avoids this issues. In that case the client is only modifying specific associations without touching the other ones.